# enumerateでindexと数字を＋時の質問

Tags: python

以下の様なリストがあるとします。

```
a=list(range(1,6))
a.reverse()
```

この時、以下のコードでは成功するのですが

```
b=[i+g for i,g in enumerate(a)]
print(b)
```

以下のコードだと `i` が "can not assign to operator" と出ます。

```
b=[]
for i,g in enumerate(a):
    i+g=c
    b.append(c)
print(b)
```

内包表記だと上手くいくのに、分けて書くとNGなのはなぜですか？
初歩的なところだと思いますが、回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 単に`i+g=c`の代入方向が間違いで、`c=i+g`が正しいからでは？

Comment: kunifさん、ありがとうございます。それっぽいです！！解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

`i+g=c` の代入方向が間違いで、正しくは `c=i+g` でした。
コメントありがとうございました。